# How to retain and retrieve image details in Drupal 7 Ajax Form with Add More option?

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

**My custom module code:**

[image: This is the screenshot of my form]

```
  <?php
  function my_module_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['form-example'] = array( 
    'title' => 'My Module Form', 
    'description' => 'A form to mess around with.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
    'page arguments' => array('my_module_form'), 
    'access callback' => TRUE
  );
      
  return $items;
}

function my_module_form($form, &$form_state, $no_js_use = FALSE) {  
  
  $form['file'] = array(
        '#type' => 'file',
        '#title' => t('Image'),
        '#description' => t('Upload an image'),
  );
  
    $form['menu'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<b>Add More:</b>'
    );
    
      $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
      $form['names_fieldset'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Add more images'),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      );

      if (empty($form_state['num_names'])) {
        $form_state['num_names'] = 1;
      }
      
      for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_names']; $i++) {       
        $form['names_fieldset']['name'][$i][0]= array(
             '#title' => t('Image'),
             '#type' => 'file',
             '#weight' => '5',
             '#description' => t('Upload an image'),
        );
      }
          
      $form['names_fieldset']['add_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Add one more'),
        '#submit' => array('my_module_add_more_add_one'),
        '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'my_module_add_more_callback',
          'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
        ),
      );
      if ($form_state['num_names'] > 1) {
        $form['names_fieldset']['remove_name'] = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => t('Remove one'),
          '#submit' => array('my_module_add_more_remove_one'),
          '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'my_module_add_more_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
          ),
        );
      }
  
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),    
  );
  
  $form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_add_more_submit';
    if ($no_js_use) {
    if (!empty($form['names_fieldset']['remove_name']['#ajax'])) {
      unset($form['names_fieldset']['remove_name']['#ajax']);
    }
    unset($form['names_fieldset']['add_name']['#ajax']);
  }    
  return $form;
} 


function my_module_add_more_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['names_fieldset'];
}

function my_module_add_more_add_one($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['num_names']++;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
   //$form_state['no_redirect'] = TRUE;
}

function my_module_add_more_remove_one($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['num_names'] > 1) {
    $form_state['num_names']--;
  }
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function my_module_add_more_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $file = $form_state['values']['file']."<br \>";
    $validators = array();
    $file = file_save_upload('file', $validators, 'public://uploads');  
    print_r($file);     
    exit();
}
```

When i submit the form, i am trying to get the details of images, that are added through Add More option. But i am not able to get them. However i am only able to get the details of the first image (and able to upload it).

I want to know two things here:

1. How can i retrieve the details of the images that are added with Add More option (fieldset), and how can i upload them ?
2. When i browse and select an image in the fieldset, it is not retained in the form, after adding another image field. How to retain the selected images in fieldset ?

Comment: It might help to understand what is happening by debugging through the core `file` module. For testing, add a file field to a content type and upload the file. Watch what happens.

Comment: The file is getting uploaded fine. But the issue is with multiple image fields in a fieldset.

Answer (score 5):

Look at this article -- http://evolvingweb.ca/story/poutine-maker-introduction-field-api-drupal-7-part-1 -- as it has some information on something missing in your code. $delta. $delta is the id assigned to values of fields, even if your field only has 1 item.

Answer (score 4):

What do you see when you var_dump the file field you created? If you get all the information along with those added using 'Add one more' button, you can learn the correct structure of the values using: `echo "<pre>"; print_R($form_state['values']); echo "</pre>":`

Comment: When i var_dump the file field  that i created (**var_dump($form['file']);**), i could not see any values for the selected images in the entire form. I could only get details like field type, title and description.

Comment: Nop! its not $form['file'] in your submit function, all the submitted values are in $form_state.

Comment: I got a blank page after using: **print_r($form_state['values']['file']);** in the form submit function.

Comment: Why don't you just try with `print_R($form_state);exit;` in your ubmit function? You can not use print_R($form_state['values']['file'] because your fields name is not 'file', right?

Comment: Still i got the form values as empty. However i am only able to upload the first file (the one choosen from the first field in form).

Comment: Now I doubt whether what i am trying to achieve is possible in drupal. Any way of achieving it?

Comment: Please have a look at these links:
http://drupal.org/node/1762202
http://drupal.org/node/878770
http://drupal.org/node/1957290

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

The first issue is that your submit function only deals with the first upload field which is indeed called "file". But does absolutely nothing to handle the other fields.

A second issue is that it will upload and save the first field every time you click on "Add one more" which will duplicate your upload. You would not experience this issue without AJAX, but if you want to add that, you will.

I would make the following changes:

1. Remove the `$form['#tree'] = TRUE` and add it to the fieldset instead. `$form['names_fieldsets']['#tree'] = TRUE;` after you declare the fieldset of course.
2. Change the way you declare the file fields in the fieldset (inside the `for` loop) to this:

   ```
   for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_names']; $i++) {
     $form['names_fieldset'][$i]['name']= array(
       '#title' => t('Image'),
       '#type' => 'file',
       '#weight' => '5',
       '#description' => t('Upload an image'),
       // We need this to know which file element this is.
       // By default drupal would name all as files[names_fieldset]
       '#name' => 'files[names_fieldset_' . $i . '_name]',
     );
   }
   ```
3. I would change the submit function like this (note that I assume you also do my above suggested changes):

   ```
   function my_module_add_more_submit($form, &$form_state) {
     if ($form_state['values']['op'] == 'Submit') {
       $validators = array();
       $files = array();
       if (!empty($_FILES['files']['name']['file'])) {
         $files[] = file_save_upload('file', $validators, file_default_scheme() . '://uploads');
       }
       foreach ($form_state['values']['names_fieldset'] as $name => $field) {
         if ($name != 'add_name') {
           $file_name = implode('_', $form['names_fieldset'][$name]['name']['#parents']);
           if (!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][$file_name])) {
             $files[] = file_save_upload($file_name, $validators, file_default_scheme() . '://uploads');
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

With this changes we set a form field name aware that's inside a tree. We only trigger uploads when the "Submit" button is clicked and only for form fields that actually had a file added to them. Also we upload using the default scheme and don't use always the public one.

Of course the code need some messages for the user to know how many files did upload, names, or any other deemed worthy info.